# Where to find printable ISO paper sizes chart?

Tags: print-production, paper-size

I am trying to find the right paper size for personal notebook I am making and though I know ISO sizes I want, I need to hold them to be sure. The best way is to find chart that is print-friendly and print it, cut the sizes I want (A5, A6, C5, C6, B5, B6) and see how they feel in hand. They all can be fit inside A4 sheet which I have plenty of in my printer. Here's the kind of thing I am looking for but at least in 150 DPI and will appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction:

[image]

Comment: I assume that you have run web searches, and either came up blank so far, or what you have found didn't satisfy your needs. This could help others to suggest better results or search approaches.

Comment: Yes. I can't find other standards like B and C that would fir into printable A4 sheet. I need B5, B6, C5 and C6 charts inside A4 paper.

Comment: Do you plan on having anything printed in this notebook, or will they be blank pages?

Comment: I Don't understand your question. But here's the website with all the paper sizes: http://www.papersizes.org/ If you want a printable chart at 150ppi, simply draw it yourself with InDesign or Illustrator. I really don't understand why you need a chart at 150ppi while you can simply use a ruler and exacto, and cut your paper for your tests. If you want a LOT of other paper with a size that isn't available in offices stores, again you can ask a printer and have the paper trimmed to the size you want and in large quantities.

Comment: @Dre Pages will be lined with small decoration printed.

Comment: @go-meek I just wanted to have printed charts for reference and to cut out sizes I want without using ruler and drafting lines. Just out of the box hassle-free cutting... And I don't have InDesign or Illustrator.

Comment: All the print charts are available online. You can use any design design software, there's free ones too similar to Indesign and Illustrator Inkscape, Scribus).  You can maybe look at stock pictures sites or ask your book store to order charts, they might have a catalog. But not sure you're at the right place to ask where to buy charts.

Comment: I have Paint.NET @go-meek

Comment: @Boris_yo One thing to bear in mind if printed commercially is that the printer will probably require at least half an inch all around for bleed, grip and crop marks; this makes certain size choices more economical than others. There's a reason B-sized sheets are often used for printing;  they can be trimmed down to various A sizes with very little wastage. E.g. a printer with a B2 press can get 1x A2, 2x A3s or 4x A4s out of 1x B2 sheet. Conversely, they'll only be able to get 1x B3 or 2x B4 out of the same sized sheet, plus a lot of wastage (just under 50%), which you will be paying for.

Comment: @Dre Sorry if I was not clear but I talked about my own Brother printer at home. I just need to print A4 sized sheets with charts for B5, B6, C5, C6. Anyway I better print A4 normal sheet, draw lines with pencil and cut out this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For A sizes you can just fold an A4 sheet in half to get A5 etc.